# multiple ingress controller setup on eks , not working together

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I have multiple Ingress,  ingress-nginx-internal controller and ingress-nginx-external controller not working togeather, even though I am using a different class .

`--ingress-class=nginx-internal` for internal ingress controller

`--ingress-class=nginx-external` for external ingress controller

not getting any error in ing logs.

Comment: Can you expand on what is not working in the setup ? What is the topology ?

Comment: this is nlb, and ingress object is not loading in browser, but as an IP address those are working fine.